# Java EE named query join

Tags: java, database, jpa, named-query

I have two entities

```
   @Entity    
    public class Tabulka{

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tabulka")
    private List<VysledkyHraca> vysledkyHraca;
.
.
.

}
```

and

```
    @Entity
    public class VysledkyHraca{

    @ManyToOne
        private Tabulka tabulka;
.
.
.

    }
```

this created to tables: tabulka with with id and ...
and VysledkyHraca with id .. and id_tabulka

If I want to retrive all tabulka... well, it's pretty Easy:

```
@NamedQuery(name = Tabulka.Q_GET_ALL_TABULKY, query = "SELECT t FROM Tabulka t ")
```

but now I want to retrive all tabulka and then list of VysledkyHraca

I try this `@NamedQuery(name = Tabulka.Q_GET_ALL_JOINTABULKY, query = "SELECT t FROM Tabulka t  join t.vysledkyHraca")` but it doesnt work. thx for help

Comment: You need much more information than "but it doesnt work". A stack trace, details about WHAT didn't work, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

join requires an alias

If you just want it fetched, use "join fetch" (with no alias)

Comment: hm and what is the different between join fetch and join ?

Answer (score 0):

You are still selecting Tabulkas in the second query. Try:

```
 SELECT vh FROM Tabulka t join t.vysledkyHraca vh
```